# Subtracting 2 columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

Hi I wanna subtract Coverage from Bill and Put it in Total from my Table TotalBill

It's going to be like this:
Bill - Coverage = Total

```
+------+-----------+-------+  
| Bill | Coverage  | Total |    
+------+-----------+-------+  
| 1300 |       300 |  NULL |    
| 2000 |      1600 |  NULL |     
+------+-----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your are looking for this

```
   UPDATE 
     TotalBill
   SET 
     Total = Bill - Coverage
```

Comment: Hello, I want to set it from the start because I need to update every time I want to show the table. Is It like This:
CREATE TABLE TotalBill (Billing DECIMAL (8,2) NOT NULL, Coverage DECIMAL (8,2) NOT NULL, Total DECIMAL (9,2) NOT NULL, SET (Total = Billing - Coverage), PRIMARY KEY (Total);